# When is the Schur multiplier complemented in $R / [F, R]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups

A normal subgroup $K \trianglelefteq G$ is *complemented* if there is a subgroup $H \le G$ such that $H \cap K = \{e\}$ and $G = HK$, i.e., $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(group_theory))).

Let $G$ be a group with a free presentation $G \cong F / R$. Hopf's formula asserts that the Schur multiplier $M(G)$ is given by $M(G) \cong (R \cap [F, F]) / [R, F]$. When is $M(G)$ complemented in $R / [R, F]$?

Comment: Take a look on Schur-Zassenhaus theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but my prime focus is on free groups.

Comment: Your conditions are *not* enough to ensure $G$ is the direct product of $H$ and $K$: that would be the case only if $H$ and $K$ are normal. Anyway, what do you hope to say about subgroups of free groups? Some are complemented, others aren't.

Comment: At the moment it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited the question. ple4ase have4 a look.

Comment: At least one of $H$ or $K$ needs to be normal in order for $G$ to be a semidirect product.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to focus on what you want, as I understand it. Let me know if I got it wrong. I think the question phrased in this way will be better received and you should quickly get an answer.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thank you very much for rewriting my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $R \le F$, $R/[R,F]$ is an abelian group.

$$R/(R \cap [F,F]) \cong R[F,F]/[F,F] \le F/[F,F],$$

which is free abelian, so $R/(R \cap [F,F])$ is also free abelian, and hence $(R \cap [F,F])/[R,F]$ has a complement in $R/[R,F]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not Know the proof of the fact the subgroups of a free abelian group is complemented. Please give me some references.

Comment: It is not true in general that subgroups of free abelian groups are complemented and I didn't say that they were. I said that if $G$ is abelian, $N \le G$ and $G/N$ is free abelian, then $N$ is complemented in $G$.

Comment: Can you give the proof of the statement stated in the last comment?

Comment: It's the same as the proof for general free groups. Let $\{ g_iN \mid i \in I \}$ be a free generating set for the free abelian group $G/N$. Then their inverse images $g_i$ generate a complement of $N$ in $G$.

Comment: I think same proof may work for any free group $F$ and its subgroup $R$ such that $F/R$ is free?